# Heroku and Dynadot DNS

Tags: heroku, dns

I've just purchased a domain on Dynadot and have no idea how to setup their DNS. When I did it on Namecheap it was much simpler.

I have added 2 domains in my heroku app:

1. `mydomain.com` -> `mysecretdnsfornosubdomain.herokudns.com`
2. `www.mydomain.com` -> `mysecretdnsforwwwsubdomain.herokudns.com`

Now, the Dynadot asks me to do this:
[image]

What should I enter in these fields to get this working? On Namecheap I just had to add 2 records:

1. One `ALIAS RECORD` for `@` host with e.g. `mysecretdnsfornosubdomain.herokudns.com` as the value
2. Second `CNAME RECORD` for `www` host with e.g. `mysecretdnsforwwwsubdomain.herokudns.com` as the value

Answer (score 1):

First look if dynadot support alias if yes than the setup should be exact same as namecheap.
If not you can use a dns service (dnsimple or cloudflate) which support alias.

I'm case you want to use dynadot and heroku.

1 Add pointdns add-on

2 Add all dns records to pointdns

3 Replace dynadot ns by pointdns NS something like *.pointhq.com

Comment: namecheap allow Alias so you point the naked/root domain as you already mentioned in the post.